# eWitness integration is failing with 'witness recipient not enbled'

Tags: docusignapi

I've followed the instructions here:
[Is there a way to send an envelope using the eWitness feature?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61402053/is-there-a-way-to-send-an-envelope-using-the-ewitness-feature/61431348#61431348)

However I get the following error:
**{"errorCode":"WITNESS_NOT_ENABLED","message":"Witness recipient type not enabled."}**

I have ensured that I've linked the witness to the signer; i.e.

1. Create the signer recipient object. Remember the recipientId you're
   using.
2. Create a witness recipient object with two attributes:
   recipientId (a new value), and witnessFor, set to the recipientId of
   the signer.

Happy to post the request payload; question was whether anyone has come across this message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ask DocuSign to enable the witness feature for your account.

Comment: Hi Larry.  Been sending emails to their support and then sales team but no response; I'm sure what you are saying will be correct but just need to hear back from them.

Comment: Sorry to hear that Shak! Connect with me on LinkedIn and we'll try to sort it out. -- Larry Kluger

Comment: Once the feature was enabled, the our integration began to work.  Thanks Larry.